# \vec{p_{\bar p}} renders strangely

Tags: amsmath, accents, subscripts

When I do:

```
\vec{p_{\bar p}}
```

I get:

[image: strange rendering]

instead of

[image: proper-ish rendering]

with the `\vec` shifted over a bit. Why does this happen?

(Also, `\vec{\mbox{p_{\bar p}}}` renders identically, even though `\mbox{p_{\bar p}}` looks fine, which clashes with my previous mental model of `\mbox` – I thought that things outside the box don't really affect things inside the box; guess I'm wrong.)

Comment: Use `\vec{p}_{\bar p}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: now you win! Its a tie!

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't quite clear. That's how I got my second image, but what if I want the `\vec` arrow to be shifted to the right to be centered over the entire p_p "block"?

Comment: (Also not suggesting that this would be the best way to typeset this, but I'm wondering why what I tried breaks.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems connected to the bug already examined in the question [Why do arguments to nested \tilde or \breve commands reappear when amsmath is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/why-do-arguments-to-nested-tilde-or-breve-commands-reappear-when-amsmath-is-us)

Indeed, if `amsmath` is not loaded, your code works fine.

The solution is to avoid nesting:

```
$\vec{p}_{\bar{p}}$
```

which is, in my opinion, more mathematically sound.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the explanation (both here and on the other question)!