# Bug related to \hat{} in amsmath

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to typeset an equation that contains the following:

```
\begin{align*}
\hat{\E[(R_{i}-\hat R_{i})^{2}]} 
\end{align*}
```

However, this is what I get

[image: Bug?]

Is this a bug? Is there any way around it? I'd like the "hat" to be over the whole expression, not just the expectation operator which I've defined as:

```
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
```

Comment: There is also a `\widehat` command...

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/why-do-arguments-to-nested-tilde-or-breve-commands-reappear-when-amsmath-is-us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
\widehat{\E[(R_{i}-\hat{R}_{i})^{2}]}
```

or if you want a bigger hat see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol) question.