# Matrix derivation

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrays

I would like to display a matrix with a dot (derivative) on top of it. The entry of this matrix shall consist of arbitrary symbols.

When I write

```
 \begin{align}
   \dot{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}}
 \end{align}
```

everything works fine. However,

```
 \begin{align}
   \dot{\begin{pmatrix} \hat{x} \\ \hat{y} \end{pmatrix}}
 \end{align}
```

results in a weird series of errors (Illegal units of measure etc.).

How can I display a matrix derivation with hats (or other ornaments) on my `x` and `y` variables? Neither changing from `pmatrix` to `array` nor setting brackets did bring any improvements.

A complete example of the problem reads:

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs,amssymb,dsfont}
 \begin{document}
   \begin{align}
     \dot{\begin{pmatrix} \hat{x} \\ \hat{y} \end{pmatrix}} % Problem!
   \end{align}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to TeX.sx! Could you provide a MWE?

Comment: this is kind of a recurring problem and there is a duplicate somewhere. My personal recommendation is that put `d\dt` next to the matrix instead of the dot. It often looks like a dirt on the screen.

Comment: @percusse - Agreed, this might me more of a mathematical point but I think a dot above a matrix would be poor notation. `d/dt` is much clearer Also, dot above the vector may be ambiguous of whether it is just a dot above the first element.

Comment: I am aware of the mathematical and optical ambiguities of this notation. Nevertheless, dots are commonly used as derivation symbols in physics.

Comment: Your complete example is incomplete please make it show the problem described, not missing `\begin{document}`

Comment: @Mico that's expected, `\dot` in latex is just the tex primitive mathaccent.`\dot` in `amsmath` is a different thing altogether:-)

Comment: @Enrico, well aware that physicists use the dot notation for derivation, however I've never seen a single physicist use that notation on a matrix presumably because it may get *lost* as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`amsmath` has some fancy code for double accents and having `\hat` inside `\dot` triggers bits of that in unintended ways. Easiest is to pre-set the inner expression in a box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathrsfs,amssymb,dsfont}
\begin{document}

 \begin{align}
 \sbox0{$\begin{pmatrix}\hat{x} \\ \hat{y} \end{pmatrix}$}\dot{\usebox{0}}
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/why-do-arguments-to-nested-tilde-or-breve-commands-reappear-when-amsmath-is-us for reference

Comment: After seeing the image I'd warmly recommend the OP not to use this notation.

Comment: @egreg yes:-) although after seeing your other answer maybe this could be closed as duplicate (same answer although question is a bit different)

Comment: @ egreg I did not find this question although I searched for quite a wile. And I agree, it does not look so good.