# mathabx and mathtools: \widetilde{} and \dot{} problem

Tags: math-mode, accents, mathtools, mathabx

The problem is the odd placement of g in the second line in the `align` environment. Strangely, the `\dot{}`-character is only misplaced if it is followed by another character. I need the `mathabx` package for some symbols and would therefore prefer an alternative to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font). Without mathabx everything works as expected.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{g\dot{g}}\\
\widetilde{\dot{g}g}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is the same as exposed in [Why do arguments to nested \tilde or \breve commands reappear when amsmath is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/why-do-arguments-to-nested-tilde-or-breve-commands-reappear-when-amsmath-is-us) Here it appears in a less spectacular way, the effect of `mathabx` is just to produce it also with `widetilde`. The solution is always the same:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newsavebox{\accentbox}
\newcommand{\compositeaccents}[2]{%
  \sbox\accentbox{$#2$}#1{\usebox\accentbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\compositeaccents{\widetilde}{g\dot{g}}\\
\compositeaccents{\widetilde}{\dot{g}g}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can use whatever name you want instead of `\compositeaccents`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Especially your answer in the linked question above is very instructive.

Answer (score 5):

One fix is to put the expression in a box first (incorporating it into a redefined `\widetilde`):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx} 
\newsavebox\tempbox
\let\svwidetilde\widetilde
\renewcommand\widetilde[1]{\sbox\tempbox{$#1$}\svwidetilde{\usebox{\tempbox}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{g\dot{g}}\\
\widetilde{\dot{g}g}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, one can, as a workaround, use `scalerel` package to stretch the tilde, and `stackengine` package to set it atop the expression.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx} 
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{g\dot{g}}\\
\stackon[0pt]{\dot{g}g}{\hstretch{1.4}{\sim}}\\
%\widetilde{\dot{g}g}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]