# Consistency versus aesthetics with respect to \tilde and \widetilde

Tags: typography, math-operators

I am currently working on a paper which heavily uses `\tilde` for both lower case letters and capitals in math bold font.

When using `\tilde` for lower case letters, everything looks perfectly fine, but `\tilde{\mathbf{X}}` looks a little silly because the symbol is so out of proportion relative to the symbol below it. My solution to this has been to use `\widetilde` only for capitals instead, but I am concerned about consistency and any personal bias on the aesthetics of tiny tildes over large symbols.

To me, the problem is twofold:

1. If I use `\widetilde`, I am essentially using two different symbols, `\tilde` and `\widetilde` to mean the same thing.
2. When `\widetilde` is used inside a line of text, it disrupts the spacing (in a very minor way) unless I override that behavior. This would also be inconsistent with the way I've written to avoid any disruption of line spacing by things such as using `\displaystyle` for my in-text limits and summations.

At this time, I think the best solutions are to either just use a tiny tilde for everything; only use `\widetilde` in the math environment for capitals and `\tilde` in-text; or suppress the added spacing because most readers will never notice the difference and this is a somewhat pedantic detail anyway (Is messing with ``vertical kerning'' a big deal?).

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: I hope I do not misunderstand you. Take a look whether this helps: [mathabx and mathtools: \widetilde{} and \dot{} problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153868/mathabx-and-mathtools-widetilde-and-dot-problem).

Comment: Which font (family) do you use? In some font families -- though not Computer/Latin Modern -- the widetilde/widehat "accents" are indeed quite prominent. If you use CM/LM fonts, your mixed approach -- small accents over lowercase letters and wide accents over uppercase letters -- should be OK. If you have any misgivings about risking confusion among your readers, just provide a paragraph somewhere early on in the document explaining any notational conventions feel explaining.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. After some research it looks like I am using Computer Modern (This was surprisingly difficult laborious on a Mac). If you would like to put this as an answer, I will be happy to select it.

I will make an effort to update my username in a timely fashion, but I have to leave for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recently revised answer at [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode/101138#101138) is directly applicable to your problem.  I don't change any definitions in moving it from there to here, but in this MWE, I also show how it can be used in text mode, and with `\mathbf` which was your particular interest.  Because it defaults its argument to math mode, one actually surrounds the argument in `$` to get it in text mode.  It is defined to work across all math styles as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2014/03/10]
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{-.1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\sim}{.5467\wd0}}{.7\ht0}%
%    .2mu is the kern imbalance when clipping white space
%    .5467++++ is \ht/[kerned \wd] aspect ratio for \sim glyph
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\def\test#1{$%
  \reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

Text mode: \reallywidetilde{$a$} \reallywidetilde{$abcde$} 

Mathbf: \reallywidetilde{\mathbf{X}} \reallywidetilde{\mathbf{XYZ}}

Normal math (different styles):

\test{abcdefghijklm}
\test{abcdefghijk}
\test{abcdefghi}
\test{abcdefg}
\test{abcde}
\test{abc}
\test{ab}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. Although it is too late for the problem I had, this looks like a good alternative for me in the future.