# Combination of \dot, \tilde and \widetilde: a predefinite alternative symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages, mtpro, newtx

Starting from this MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[\tilde{\dot{u}}=-i \omega \tilde{u}\]
\[\widetilde{\dot{u}}=-i \omega \widetilde{u}\]
\end{document}
```

that produces this image:

[image]

reading this question, [mathabx and mathtools: \widetilde{} and \dot{} problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153868/mathabx-and-mathtools-widetilde-and-dot-problem), I was trying to understand if exists a symbol like `\tilde`, or `\widetilde` (without macro) that has more coverage than the `u` or another letter.

In fact, with the symbol `\dot`, you can see that `\tilde` is small and it has little coverage with the letter `u`. While if I use`\widetilde` it looks higher, than the dot, but too big in lenght.

Answer (score 1):

Reading very good the guide pag. 15 (I obviously didn't read it very well), http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/mtpro2.pdf

[image]

there are other commands: `\wwhat`, `\wwtilde`, etc.. I'm using these two in relation to my requests of my question. I am totally satisfied and here I have inserted my MWE hoping that it will be useful to someone.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tilde{\dot{u}}=-i \omega \tilde{u}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\widehat{\dot{u}}=-i \omega \widehat{u}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\widetilde{\dot{u}}=-i \omega \widetilde{u}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\wwhat{\dot{u}}=-i \omega \wwhat{u}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\wwtilde{\dot{u}}=-i \omega \wwtilde{u}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```