# Serious problem with \widebar

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I met across a serious problem using the `widebar` math command defined by Hendrik Vogt as an answer to [question 16337](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package/60253#60253). It worked fine until I used  `\(wide)hat` in its argument. Here is a M(non)WE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
%If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
    \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
%Determine the italic correction:
    \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
    \dimen@\wd\tw@
    \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
%Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
    \divide\dimen@ 3
    \@tempdima\wd\tw@
    \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
%Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
    \divide\@tempdima 10
    \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
%Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
    \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
%The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
    \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
    \if#31
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
      \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
%Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
      \let\final@kern#2%
      \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
      \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
    \else
      \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \macc@depth\@ne
  \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
  \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
  \macc@set@skewchar\relax
  \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
%The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
  \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
  \else
%If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
%a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
      \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$  \widebar{f \circ \widehat{x}}  $

\end{document}
```

The .log file delivers this:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
<to be read again> 
                   \macc@style 
l.195 ...i(f)^*} = \widebar{f \circ \widehat{x}} =
                                                   \widebar f \circ \widehat...
If you really absolutely need more capacity, …
```

Without the `\widehat` command, it's perfect:

[image]
Can anyone help?

Comment: `\widebar` redefines `\mathaccent`, which `\widehat` relies upon. Also, nesting accents is a dark corner in `amsmath`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/why-do-arguments-to-nested-tilde-or-breve-commands-reappear-when-amsmath-is-us

Comment: @ egreg: So there's probably nothing to be done? `\overline` as a replacement isn't just as fine, even adding some math kerning…

Comment: By the way, the hack suggested in my answer to the linked question (`\compositeaccents`) works, but the bar is not correctly computed as in `\widebar{f\circ x}`.

Comment: @I'll look at it. I also have the possibility to define a `varwidebar` for that kind of special case, using the \widebar command from  `mathabx` (it supports `\widehat` in its argument, but may have other problems).

Answer (score 7):

REVISED to add important note at end:

Based on my answer at [Big tilde in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode/101138#101138), I adapted similar approaches for a wide hat and bar.  After showing them in various math styles, I show composites of them, including the function of interest to you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2014/03/10]
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{1pt-\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\sim}{.5467\wd0}}{.5\ht0}%
%    .2mu is the kern imbalance when clipping white space
%    .5467++++ is \ht/[kerned \wd] aspect ratio for \sim glyph
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{-1.0\ht0+.5pt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.15mu\char'136}{2.6\wd0}}{1.4\ht0}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\newcommand\reallywidebar[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{.5pt+\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \rule{\wd0}{\dimexpr.3\LMpt+.3pt}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\def\test#1{$%
  \reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}$~$
  \reallywidehat{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidehat{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidehat{#1}$~$
  \reallywidebar{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidebar{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidebar{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

Normal math (different styles):

\test{abcde}
\test{abc}
\test{a}

Composites:

$\reallywidebar{D + \reallywidehat{C +\reallywidetilde{ag}}}$

$\reallywidebar{f \circ \reallywidehat{x}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

IMPORTANT NOTE: (further revised based on better understanding)

I would make one interesting observation.  The way TeX handles different mathstyles automatically is with `\mathchoice`, in which four boxes are constructed, and only one of them used, depending on the local mathstyle.  The `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` construct of the `scalerel` package used in this MWE is a glorified version of `\mathchoice` that helps save on typing.

But regardless of whether `\mathchoice` or `\ThisStyle` is used to achieve the result, the nesting of `\mathchoices` can become very computationally inefficient.

For cases like this, it might make sense to override the `\mathchoice` and tell it which of the boxes to use.  One can achieve that by defining these macros:

```
\def\fixDS#1{{\renewcommand\mathchoice[4]{##1}#1}}% FORCE \displaystyle
\def\fixTS#1{{\renewcommand\mathchoice[4]{##2}#1}}% FORCE \textstyle
\def\fixSS#1{{\renewcommand\mathchoice[4]{##3}#1}}% FORCE \scriptstyle
\def\fixsS#1{{\renewcommand\mathchoice[4]{##4}#1}}% FORCE \scriptscriptstyle
```

In the case of my 2nd to last example, because all `\mathchoice` symbols occur in `\displaystyle`, one could save a lot of compilation time by invoking the call as

```
$\fixDS{\reallywidebar{D + \reallywidehat{C +\reallywidetilde{ag}}}}$
```

A similar approach can be used if the `\mathchoice`s occur in different mathstyles. For example, The first of the following forms constructs many boxes before choosing one, while the second form bypasses the `\mathchoice` branching.

```
$\reallywidebar{A_{\reallywidebar{A_{\reallywidebar{A}}}}}$

$\fixDS{\reallywidebar{A_{\fixSS{\reallywidebar{A_\fixsS{\reallywidebar{A}}}}}}}$
```

This hardwiring approach need only to be considered if the computational cost of `\mathchoice` nesting presents a notable slowdown in compilation.

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

After having been informed that the above approach for `\reallywidehat` did not look so pretty for `newtxmath`, I reworked a version for that font.  Also tweaked `\reallywidetilde` to match the font characteristics:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}[2014/03/10]
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand\reallywidetilde[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{1pt-\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.2mu\sim}{.65\wd0}}{.5\ht0}%
%    .2mu is the kern imbalance when clipping white space
%    .5467++++ is \ht/[kerned \wd] aspect ratio for \sim glyph
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{-1.0\ht0+1.8pt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\SavedStyle\mkern.15mu\mathchar"0362}{1.3\wd0}}{1.15\ht0}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\newcommand\reallywidebar[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#1$}%
  \stackengine{.5pt+\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#1$}{%
    \rule{\wd0}{\dimexpr.3\LMpt+.3pt}%
  }{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}%
}}

\def\test#1{$%
  \reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidetilde{#1}$~$
  \reallywidehat{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidehat{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidehat{#1}$~$
  \reallywidebar{#1}\,
  \scriptstyle\reallywidebar{#1}\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\reallywidebar{#1}
$\par}

\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

Normal math (different styles):

\test{abcde}
\test{abc}
\test{a}

Composites:

$\reallywidebar{D + \reallywidehat{C +\reallywidetilde{ag}}}$

$\reallywidebar{f \circ \reallywidehat{x}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user49915 Just tweaked `.5467` to `.65` and all is well.

Comment: @user0  I am sorry, I do not have access to that font, so I can't check.  But I would start with my answers at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol/101136#101136 to see if they work for you.

Comment: @user0 The first of the two solutions at the cited answer seems to work with `unicode-math`.

Comment: @user0 The first `-.6pt` affects the left edge, the 2nd `-.6pt` affects the right edge, and the `0.5ex` affects the hat height, and the `[1pt]` affects the gap between text and hat.  Have at it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed [the code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253) for `\widebar` so that nesting of accents is possible now. I didn't do any real testing, but it works nicely in your example:

[image: output]

`$\widebar{f \circ \widehat{x}}$`

Comment: Thank you so much! It was really lacking in latex. I'll test it in real conditions as soon as possible.

Comment: @Hendtik Vogt: I began testing. Unfortunately there's a problem with the `\mathbf` command: when I type `$\widebar{\mathbf{F}\circ x}`,  x is also in boldface. Similarly with `mathrm`, `mathtt` and probably any change of math alphabet, but not with `\bm`. A work around, for the moment, consists in  writing `$\widebar{\mathbf F}\circ x}$`, which is not really satisfying.

Comment: @Bernard: Oh, right. The old version already had that problem, too, so it appears that the new version is still better. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Thankk you dor delving into this ˆproblem. Of course there was a typo in my previous comment: I meant `$\widebar{{\mathbf F}\circ x}$`.