# Difficulties implementing Equations

Tags: math-mode, formatting, equations

I am trying to write this equations in TeXnic Center, but so far, I am not very successful.
The equations I want to write are here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.opticalflow-class.html - Horn&Schunk method.

```
The Horn-Schunk method, by assuming that the optical flow is smooth over the entire image, computes an estimate of the velocity field, that minimizes this equation:
\begin{flushleft}

    \[
E = \int \!\!\! \int ($I_x$u + $I_y$v + $I_t$)^2 dxdy + \alpha \int \!\!\! \int (\frac{\partial \textit{u}}{\partial x}^2 + \frac{\partial \textit{u}}{\partial y}^2 + \frac{\partial \textit{v}}{\partial x}^2 + \frac{\partial \textit{v}}{\partial y}^2)dxdy
    \]
\end{flushleft}

where \alpha is the smoothness term of the velocity field, 
    \[
    \frac{\partial \textit{u}}{\partial x}
\]
 and 
     \[
    \frac{\partial \textit{v}}{\partial x} 
 \]
 are the spatial derivatives of the optical velocity component \textit{u}. The \alpha regularization parameter controls the strength of the smoothness constraint and is usually selected heuristically. The Horn-Schunck method minimizes the previous equation to obtain the velocity field, [u v], for each pixel in the image, which is given by the following equations:

    \[
        \stackrel u{k+1}{x,y} = \stackrel u{-k}{x,y} - \frac{$I_x$[$I_x$\stackrel u{-k}{x,y} + $I_y$\stackrel v{-k}{x,y} + $I_t$]}{\alpha^2 + $I_x$^2 + $I_y$^2
    \]

    \[
        \stackrel v{k+1}{x,y} = \stackrel v{-k}{x,y} - \frac{$I_y$[$I_x$\stackrel u{-k}{x,y} + $I_y$\stackrel v{-k}{x,y} + $I_t$]}{\alpha^2 + $I_x$^2 + $I_y$^2
    \]
```

I am newbie in LateX, and when I compile, it doesn't puts out the expected result.
Also, when I write \alpha, afterwards, the text gets formatted in a different way (see picture attached). Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: please always post _complete_ document that allows people to reproduce the problem. Don't ignore TeX error messages! You will have had an error message from `\alpha` saying it is a math mode command, and as you can see from the output everything after that is in math Use `$\alpha$`

Comment: ok @DavidCarlisle thanks. Could you help me with the equations? :/

Comment: well fix all the easy errors _as reported by TeX_ eg you don't have `$` around `\alpha`  but then you have incorrect `$` around variables that are already in math mode `\int ($I_` should be `\int (I_` with no `$`. But if you want someone to try your code make it start with `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't understand. I've already changed the \alpha to $\alpha$ and now the text is ok. The problem now is the "E" equation and the final two equations. How can I make code for some1 to try out?

Comment: As I said above you have lots of spurious `$` _within_ your displayed equations, remove them all.  Your example code as poste is just a fragment so people can not try it, you should edit it in the question so it starts `\documentclass` and has (just) the packages needed for the example and ends `\end{document}`

Comment: as you can see from the output the `$` _ends_ the math mode (and generates a TeX error)

Comment: ok, I'll see if I can do that. I have removed the $ from the "E" equation and it works now. :) The other two are the problem...

Comment: @user2205242 you have a number of other errors in you code besides the ones mentioned by David: `\textit` inside math (using it for variables is wrong, anyway), missing braces, missing arguments to `\stackrel`...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you explain me one thing? Look my initial picture. The paragraph in the beginning of the page is 20mm dislocated to the right and at the bottom, the text starts a little bit before. why? :/

Comment: That is why you should always post a _complete document_ that paragraph is indented because of some earlier code you hav enot shown. Perhaps it is a list environment or quote or abstract that is not finished. Impossible to say. If TeX generates an error message the final pdf form should just be used as a rough debugging aid, TeX just inserts things to allow it to carry on, not to make sensible output. If you have a list environment that starts but is not finished tehn there will be an error message about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close but you are over working things.

First, inside a displayed equations you do no need to enclose mathematics within dollar signs, so you can drop then `$...$`.

Secondly, your `\stackrel`'s are unnecessary and completely confused me: subscripts and superscripts are done with `_` and `^`, respectively.

Here is a cleaned up working version of your code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
E = \iint (I_xu + I_yv + I_t)^2\,dx\,dy + \alpha \iint
 (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}^2 + \frac{\partial
u}{\partial y}^2 + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}^2 +
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}^2)\,dx\,dy
\end{equation*}

where $\alpha$ is the smoothness term of the velocity field,
    \[
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
\]
 and
     \[
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
 \]
 are the spatial derivatives of the optical velocity component $u$. The $\alpha$ regularization parameter controls the strength of the smoothness constraint and is usually selected heuristically. The Horn-Schunck method minimizes the previous equation to obtain the velocity field, $[u v]$, for each pixel in the image, which is given by the following equations:

    \[
    u^{k+1}_{x,y} = u^{-k}_{x,y} - \frac{I_x[I_xu^{-k}_{x,y} + I_yv^{-k}_{x,y} + I_t]}{\alpha^2 + I_x^2 + I_y^2}
    \]

    \[
    v^{k+1}_{x,y} = v^{-k}_{x,y} - \frac{I_y[I_xu^{-k}_{x,y} + I_yv^{-k}_{x,y} + I_t]}{\alpha^2 + I_x^2 + I_y^2}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great! Thanks so much @Andrew! God Bless all of you!

Comment: Andrew, can you explain me one thing? Look my initial picture. The paragraph in the beginning of the page is 20mm dislocated to the right and at the bottom, the text starts a little bit before. why? :/

Comment: @user2205242 Can yu say exactly which paragraph you mean? If it is the `about...` then it is because this starts a new paragaph.If you delete the empty line this will fix itself.

Comment: You need to fix one more thing: The terms to the immediate right of the equal signs of the final two equations represent spatial averages. Thus thus need to be written as `\bar{u}^{k}_{x,y}` and `\bar{v}^{k}_{x,y}` rather than as `u^{-k}_{x,y}` and `v^{-k}_{x,y}`.

Comment: a couple more things ... (1) don't leave a blank line before a display -- it fouls up the vertical spacing.  (2) multiple display lines should be grouped in a multi-line environment; here i'd suggest `align*` from `amsmath`.  this suppresses unwanted page breaks as well as keeping the adjacent formulas grouped more sensibly.  (`gather` is better if you don't want alignment.)

Comment: There's an empty line before `where` that should be removed.

Answer (score 5):

I've taken a crack at cleaning up your code.

Some dos and donts:

- Don't use $...$ inside display-math mode to denote math objects; *all* objects in display-math mode are assumed to be math objects.
- Similarly, don't use `\textit{...}` to denote math items: If already in math mode, you need do nothing extra; if not, use $u$. (Some, but not all, fonts distinguish between math italics and text italics; when in math mode, use *math* italics.)
- The `flushleft` environment encasing a display-math environment achieves nothing; leave it off.
- Take care to resize various parentheses when they enclose "large" objects, using either `\left` and `\right` or, better still, optimally chosen sizing directives such as `\big` and `\bigg`.
- To write a "bar" (overline) across a variable `x`, write either `\bar{x}` or `\overline{x}` (if you want a heftier bar).
- Use `^` ("caret") to initiate superscript matter and `_` ("underline") to initiate subscript matter.
- Don't leave extra blank lines in matter that clearly is meant to be a single logical paragraph; all-blank lines initiate a paragraph break, with the first word of the new paragraph right-indented (in the amount of `\parindent`).
- When you have groups of equations (such as the last two ones in your example), try using an environment such as `align` or `align*`. Please consult the user guide of the amsmath package to find out more about these environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The Horn-Schunk method, by assuming that the optical flow is smooth over the entire image, computes an estimate of the velocity field, that minimizes this equation:
\[
E = \int \!\!\! \int \bigl(I_xu + I_yv + I_t\bigr)^2 dxdy + \alpha \int \!\!\! \int \biggl(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}^2 + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}^2 + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}^2 + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}^2\biggr)dxdy
\]
where $\alpha$ is the smoothness term of the velocity field and
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and 
$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$
are the spatial derivatives of the optical velocity component~$u$. The $\alpha$ regularization parameter controls the strength of the smoothness constraint and is usually selected heuristically. The Horn-Schunck method minimizes the previous equation to obtain the velocity field, $[u\ v]$, for each pixel in the image, which is given by the following equations:
\begin{align*}
u^{k+1}_{x,y} &= \bar{u}^{k}_{x,y} - 
\frac{I_x[I_x \bar{u}^{k}_{x,y} + I_y\bar{v}^{k}_{x,y} 
+ I_t]}{\alpha^2 + I_x^2 + I_y^2}\\
v^{k+1}_{x,y} &= \bar{v}^{k}_{x,y} - 
\frac{I_y[I_x\bar{u}^{k}_{x,y} + I_y\bar{v}^{k}_{x,y} 
+ I_t]}{\alpha^2 + I_x^2 + I_y^2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks so much! Nevertheless, the last 2 equations are not in the way that I want! Please, http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.opticalflow-class.html see the Horn Schunk method, the last two equations :/

Comment: @user2205242 - Thanks for this pointer; it looks like what you need are superscript terms. Give me a few minutes to update my answer.

Comment: someone already posted the correct answer! Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: @ Mico probably also worth mentioning that empty lines in mid-paragraph need to be avoided (I see that you've removed them :) )... It seems @user2205242 should read some introduction to LaTeX and mathmode, http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode maybe?

Comment: @Mico, can you explain me one thing? Look my initial picture. The paragraph in the beginning of the page is 20mm dislocated to the right and at the bottom, the text starts a little bit before. why? :/

Comment: @Mico I didn't quite understand your last question.. I believe that this paragraph thing is happening because of the template I am using...

Comment: @user2205242 - Compare my solution, that of the accepted answer, and the look of the expression in the "template": The spatially (locally) averaged variables should be written as `\bar{u}^{k}_{x,y}` and *not* as `u^{-k}_{x,y}`. The template you're using may be providing extra blank lines, but that shouldn't stop you from deleting them if they're not needed (and the more so if they lead to inappropriate paragraph breaks), right?

Comment: @cgnieder - Thanks for pointing this out; I've added it as a bullet point to the list of do's and don'ts.

Comment: @Mico -- the indented paragraph beginning "The Horn-Schunk method," isn't broken by a blank line, so that doesn't explain the indent of the second line.  i haven't looked into `\begin{flushleft}` to see what it might do when not separated from the text above it by a blank line, but i don't think it should have this effect.  so i surmise that the problem is caused by something earlier in the file, but not shown.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - the OP's code had a blank line between `\end{flushleft}` and "where \alpha ...". That's what -- I believe -- is responsible for the indentation of the line that begins with "where..." in his/her code. The fact that the `flushleft` environment doesn't do anything with respect to its contents (a displayed equation) is a separate matter that also needs to be fixed. A separate matter: the screenshot the OP provided isn't even remotely linked to the code he/she provided. I simply can't speculate as to what may be going on with the code that generated the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to get something sensible. Note that you have a command for double integrals, that is `\iint`. The `amsmath` package (loaded by `mathtools`) defined a number of multiline equations environment, of which I use `align*`. The `nccmath` package is here to have medium-sized fractions in in-line formulae, rather than text-style,  which is too small in my opinion.

As Mico explained the meaning of the `\stackrel` commands, I solved using the `mathabx` package that has a `widebar` command, that's better-looking in my opinion than plain `\bar`:

```
     \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, mathabx}%

     \begin{document}

    The Horn-Schunk method, by assuming that the optical flow is smooth over the entire image, computes an estimate of the velocity field, that minimizes this equation:
    \[
    E = \iint \bigl(I_x u + I_y v + I_t\bigr)^2 dxdy + \alpha \iint\left(\frac{\partial \textit{u}}{\partial x}^2 + \frac{\partial \textit{u}}{\partial y}^2 + \frac{\partial \textit{v}}{\partial x}^2 + \frac{\partial \textit{v}}{\partial y}^2\right)dxdy,
    \]
    where $ \alpha $ is the smoothness term of the velocity field, $ \mfrac{\partial \textit{u}}{\partial x} $ and $ \mfrac{\partial \textit{v}}{\partial x} $ are the spatial derivatives of the optical velocity component \textit{u}. The $ \alpha $ regularization parameter controls the strength of the smoothness constraint and is usually selected heuristically. The Horn-Schunck method minimizes the previous equation to obtain the velocity field, $ [u, v] $, for each pixel in the image, which is given by the following equations:
    \begin{align*}
      \widebar u^ {k+1}_{x,y} & = \widebar u^{k}_{x,y} - \frac{I_x[I_x \widebar u^{k}_{x,y} + I_y \widebar v^{k}_{x,y} + I_t]}{\alpha^2 + I_x^2 + I_y^2} \\
    \widebar v^{k+1}_{x,y} & = \widebar v^{k}_{x,y} - \frac{I_y[I_x \widebar u^{k}_{x,y} + I_y \widebar v^{k}_{x,y} + I_t]}{\alpha^2 + I_x^2 + I_y^2}
    \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you were also baffled by the `\stackrel`-related material. Have a look at my (updated) answer: What's needed is a combination of `\bar` (to denote spatial averages) and `^{k}_{x,y}` to denote superscript and subscript matters...

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the tip. It allowed to give a more complete answer, using `widebar` from `mathabx`.

Comment: @Bernard -- but please remember that `mathabx` changes almost *all* symbols.  (you can see the difference in the shapes of the integrals and the `\partial`s.)  see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/579) for a method of getting around that problem.

Comment: I now that, but couldn't manage to make \widebar work without loading mathabx. Maybe I didn't try enough… Actually I personally use Hendrik Vogt's solution  (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171907/serious-problem-with-widebar) but didn't dare propose it to someone who says he's a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

[
E = \int  \int (\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} {\cdot} u +\frac{ \partial I}{\partial y} \cdot v + \frac{\partial I}{\partial t}) =0 ]

[ E+\int \int (I_u+I_v+I_t)^2 dx dy  + \alpha \int 
 \int \frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial y} ) dx dy  ]

where $\alpha $ is the smoothness term of the velocity field, 
    [
    \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
]
 and 
     [
    \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} 
 ]
 are the spatial derivatives of the optical velocity component \textit{u}. The $\alpha$ regularization parameter controls the strength of the smoothness constraint and is usually selected heuristically. The Horn-Schunck method minimizes the previous equation to obtain the velocity field, [u v], for each pixel in the image, which is given by the following equations:

```
\[
    \stackrel u{k+1}{x,y} = \stackrel u{-k}{x,y} - \frac{I_x [ I_x \stackrel u{-k}{x,y} + I_y \stackrel v{-k}{x,y} + I_t]}{\alpha^2 + I_x^2 + I_y^2}
\]

\[
    \stackrel v{k+1}{x,y} = \stackrel v{-k}{x,y} - \frac{I_y[I_x \stackrel u{-k}{x,y} + I_y \stackrel v{-k}{x,y} + I_t ]}{\alpha^2 + I_x^2 + I_y^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

I have edited your file. Please compile and see the output.