# Using a widebar accent in a caption

Tags: accents

I am using a `\widebar` accent as implemented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/74872), since I don't want to use mathabx; but when I use the accent in the caption of a figure, I get a compiler error.

Here's the offending code:

```
\caption{(Blah blah) and $(\widebar{N},\widebar{X})$.
\label{fig:Markov_pf_notation}}
```

And the error:

> Argument of \Hy@tempa has an extra }.\par ...n the right $(\widebar{N},\widebar{X})$.}
>   Paragraph ended before \Hy@tempa was complete.\par ...n the right $(\widebar{N},\widebar{X})$.}

I have no trouble using `\widebar` in the body of my document, and when I comment out this instance in the caption, everything compiles correctly.

Can this implementation be fixed? Is there a comparably good implementation of `\widebar` that doesn't have this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal working example?

Comment: Change `\newcommand*\widebar` into `\DeclareRobustCommand\widebar`

Comment: Here is also stuff related to `\widebar`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171907/serious-problem-with-widebar

Answer (score 4):

The code in [Hendrik Vogt's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253/74872) has the line

```
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{%
  [...code...]
}
```

but the definition is “unsafe” for usage in moving arguments, such as captions and sectional titles. So `\widebar` is to be considered *fragile*. See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands?s=2|0.0000) for more information.

Either you keep the definition as is and use `\protect\widebar` in moving arguments, or remove the problem altogether by changing that line into

```
\newcommand{\widebar}{}% initialize
\DeclareRobustCommand*\widebar[1]{%
  [...code...]
}
```

The “initialize” line is just for ensuring `\widebar` is not yet defined, because `\DeclareRobustCommand` silently overrides previous definitions.

Comment: Would you say, four years later, that this is the recommended and preferable way to get a `\widebar` in LaTeX?

Comment: @Gaussler If not in shortage of math groups, I'd probably import `\widebar` from `mathabx`. But I nowhere said this is the preferable way, I just answered the question.

Comment: I have previously tried running out of math fonts. is the `mathabx` implementation better than this one?

Comment: @Gaussler In order to import `\widebar` from `mathabx` you *must* use a new math group.

Comment: So, is the solution provided by Vogt (properly protected) as good/equivalent to the one from `mathabx`? Because in that case, I think I prefer Vogt’s solution.