# Widecheck over two \hat

Tags: math-mode, accents

I need to write a formula with a `\widecheck` over two `\hat`.
The equation is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,mathabx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tilde{A}^\mu_\Lambda = \widehat{\widehat{G}\cdot\widehat{j^\mu_\Lambda}}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If I write this code I obtain a lot of errors (undefined control sequence, missing number treated as zero, illegal unit of measure (pt inserted), etc...).

If I use `\widehat` instead of `\widecheck`, the result is the same.
I have problems also writing

```
\widecheck{\hat{G} \cdot j}
```

because the result is not correct (G is translated to the right and overwrites j).

How can I write the `\widecheck`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is another example of the bug described in [Why do arguments to nested tilde or breve commands reappear when `amsmath` is used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/); the solutions shown there seem to apply to your case as well.

Comment: Finally I solved following egreg's suggestion.

 Thank you, egreg

Comment: I voted for closing as duplicate. Don't worry about this: it's not a judgment on your question, but our way to keep the information as tight as possible. Welcome again!

Comment: Ok, there's no problem. I've written an answer with the code I used, but I can't post it until 3a.m.!