# Math mode bug using \dot and \hat

Tags: math-mode

EDIT: I want to write this

[image]

but with a dot over the middle - for differentiation of the value in parenthesis with respect to frame I. However when I do 
`${^{\rm I}(\dot {I_{\rm p} \omega_{\rm p} \hat b_3})}$` I get

[image]

I have tried all sorts of variations that should give me something close to what I want but none of them work. The closest I can get is

[image]

by purposefully putting the hat over the whole b_3 symbol using (`\hat {b_3}`). However I need the hat to be over the b only.

Comment: MathJax is intentionally disabled on the TeX.SE, as users are likely far more interested in seeing the underlying TeX and LaTeX code than in the way it's rendered on screen.

Comment: `\rm` has been deprecated for over 20 years, don't use it (especially not in math mode)

Comment: Weird, I use it all the time. How is roman text compiled in math mode now?

Comment: `\rm` has not been defined in the latex format since 1993. It is added as a back compatibility definition by `article.cls` but not all classes do this.  for example. `\mathrm{p}`

Comment: @ThomasKirven yes although I'd be interested to know the results if you tested the patch I just posted, as I could add that to amsmath, but the code here is very delicate....

Answer (score 5):

It's another instance of [Why do arguments to nested \tilde or \breve commands reappear when amsmath is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/why-do-arguments-to-nested-tilde-or-breve-commands-reappear-when-amsmath-is-us)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox{\accentbox}
\newcommand{\compositeaccents}[2]{%
  \sbox\accentbox{$#2$}#1{\usebox\accentbox}}

\begin{document}

Bad: ${^{\rm I}(\dot {I_{\rm p} \omega_{\rm p} \hat b_3})}$

\bigskip

Good: ${}^{\mathrm{I}}\compositeaccents{\dot}{(I_{\mathrm{p}} \omega_{\mathrm{p}} \hat{b}_3})$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd avoid such notation.

Please, note that `\rm` has been deprecated for 25 years.

Comment: shouldn't I fix that in `amsmath` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're welcome!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if it isn't a feature, you should...

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to see why you are getting overprinting from your fragments, the following document produces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

${^{\mathrm{I}}\dot {({I}_{\mathrm{p}} \omega_{\mathrm{p}} \hat{b}_3})}$
\end{document}
```

As it turns out, this is an `amsmath` feature (although amsmath was not mentioned in the question) Not fully tested but one possible fix is below.
I could add something like this to `amsmath` but it needs more testing, if you have a larger real docuemnt I'd be interested if this works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\def\mathaccentV#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifmmode
    \gdef\macc@tmp{\macc@depth\@ne}%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{%
% only short circuit \mathaccentV if only one token after expansion
% not quite the right test but hard to test for only one math atom
      \ifcat$\@gobble#5\@empty$\let\mathaccentV\macc@test\fi
% end of change
      \let\use@mathgroup\@gobbletwo \let\select@group\@gobblethree
      \frozen@everymath{}$#5$%
    }%
    \macc@tmp
    \ifnum\macc@depth=\@ne
      \global\let\macc@nucleus\@empty
      \mathaccent"\accentclass@
    \else
      \@xp\macc@nested
    \fi
    #2#3#4{#5}%
    \macc@nucleus
  \else
    \@xp\nonmatherr@\csname#1\endcsname
  \fi
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}


$\dot{\hat{b}}$


${^{\mathrm{I}}\dot {({I}_{\mathrm{p}} \omega_{\mathrm{p}} \hat{b}_3})}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$^{\mathrm{I}}(\stackon[1pt]{I_{\mathrm{p}} \omega_{\mathrm{p}} \hat b_3}{.})$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also consider something less confusing, such as `$^{\mathrm{I}}[\frac{d}{dt}(I_{\mathrm{p}} \omega_{\mathrm{p}} \hat b_3)]$`

[image]

or, if the syntax makes sense, `$\frac{d}{dt}\,^{\mathrm{I}}(I_{\mathrm{p}} \omega_{\mathrm{p}} \hat b_3)$`

[image]

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. But yeah I introduce the dot notation earlier in the paper (usually it's over just one symbol so it's less confusing) so I just gotta stick with that.

Comment: Note: `amsmath` is not required for this answer.

Comment: @ThomasKirven nothing is wrong with using two notations for the same thing if one is better in some the other in other cases.