# Double printed mathematical symbol in error

Tags: math-mode, accents, mathabx

When I use `\widecheck` twice, it erroneously double prints the entry in the first `\widecheck` on top of the entry in the second `\widecheck`.  Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
\[
    A = \widecheck{\widehat{A}}
        = \sqrt{2\pi} \widecheck{(\hat\varphi\hat\varphi)}
        = \varphi* \varphi
\]
\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image: double printed A]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :)

Comment: I confirm the result with TL2022 updated on Linux.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30327/4427 and the `\compositeaccents` workaround I proposed works also in this case.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you :).  I wasn't really sure how to search for this issue, so I hadn't been able to find anything.