# What is `\Vec` (capitalised)

Tags: math-mode, vector

I stumbled accors `\Vec{...}` (notice the capitalised command). Since it is impossible to do case-sensitive searches on Google and SE, I have to ask: What does it do? Can I overwrite it? It seems to have the same effect as `\vec{...}`.

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: It could be unique to the document in question.  Search for the first occurence.

Comment: @Karlo By accident, since I wanted to define the category of vector spaces by `\Vec` (our course at least does it this way, instead of `\Vect`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I do

```
> ack '\\Vec[^f@t-]' /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/
```

(the exclusion list in the regex is just to avoid false positives) the answer is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstex.sty
774:\gdef\Vec{\RIfM@\DN@{\mathaccent@{"017E }}\else
775: \DN@{\nonmatherr@\Vec}\fi\next@}

/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath-2018-12-01.sty
876:\def\Vec{\vec}

/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
902:\def\Vec{\vec}

/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-amsmath.sty
156:\CustomizeMathJax{\let\Vec\vec}
```

So basically, the only package that defines `\Vec` is `amsmath` (`amstex.sty` is kept for backwards compatibility).

Why? If you look in `amsmath.sty` you'll see also `\Acute`, `\Hat` and so on for all math accents.

In the first versions of `amsmath`, the capitalized version was used to get stacked accents right, so you had to type

```
\Dot{\Hat{x}}
```

to get the right position of the accents. In later versions, the problem of stacking accents was solved in a different way (which adds a not so nice “feature”, but that's not the point), so the capitalized versions were redefined to be the same as the all-lowercase commands.

Using `\Vec` or `\vec` is exactly the same.

Comment: What is the not so nice “feature” added by the fix? (I had wondered about this, since I remembered using capitalisation for stacked accents, but it seems not to be recommended any more.)

Comment: @LSpice Nested accents may not work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30327/4427

Answer (score 4):

TeX differentiates between uppercase and lowercase in general, so `\vec` is not the same as `\Vec`. In plain TeX, only `\vec` is defined, but the package `amsmath` defines `\Vec` as being the same as `\vec` ("for backward compatibility" as the manual states):

```
\def\Vec{\vec}
```

So, yes, if you mean the macro as it is defined by the `amsmath` package, it does exactly the same as `\vec`. And yes, in this case you could redefine it (after having loaded `amsmath`) without affecting the defintion of `\vec`. I am not sure whether redefining it is a good idea though, since this might break things where other packages rely on the fact that `amsmath` defines the capitalized macro to be the same as the non-capitalized one.

However, since you did not provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) the above is only a guess. There might also exist other packages or document classes that define `\Vec` in their own, different way, and it could be a problem to redefine this macro in this situation, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although your answer is also helpful, I think that @egreg's answer is more complete/correct in terms of the origin of `\Vec`.

Comment: @Gargantuar Yes, I did not know about the history of this macro.